# Hide the shortcut toolbar

Tags: 8, toolbar

How can I hide the shortcut toolbar in Drupal 8.6? I need the very top menu gone (the green part highlighted in screenshot).

[image: Shortcut Toolbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using adminimal as admin theme, so go to `themes/contrib/adminimal_theme/css/adminimal.css` and paste this code in the bottom.

```
.toolbar-icon.toolbar-item {
  display: none !important;
}
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you - that will likely work, but is there a way that we can not have it render completely?

Comment: No because it is a nested menu so removing the top links will also remove the bottom links, hope it makes sense.

Comment: A big problem with this approach is that the toolbar flips to the vertical position when viewed on mobile and there is no way to collapse it,

Answer (score 0):

The Toolbar module provides tabs (that you want to hide), and links related to those tabs. Since links are listed within the tab elements in HTML it isn't easy to just hide them with CSS.

But you can use the [Toolbar Themes](https://www.drupal.org/project/toolbar_themes) module.

Toolbar Themes configuration comes with the option not to use Toolbar tabs at all.

> [ ] Show toolbar tabs
>   Unchecked this will remove tabs except for the Manage tab which is replaced by an icon.

Most people also install  [Admin Toolbar](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_toolbar) to get the drop-down menus, it significantly speeds up navigating and number of clicks.